# nicUpload says "Invalid Upload ID", cant make it works

Tags: upload, wysiwyg, nicedit

Im trying to implement nicEdit with the nicupload plugin, but when I select a file to upload it says "Failed to upload image", and the server response says "Invalid Upload ID".

This is the code that calls the script and initializes:

```
<script src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
new nicEditor({uploadURI : '../../nicedit/nicUpload.php'}).panelInstance('area1');
});
//]]>
</script>
```

The path to nicUpload.php is correct, and the code is the one that can be found in the documentation: http://nicedit.com/src/nicUpload/nicUpload.js

I made the upload folder changes, and set write permissions. According to the documentation (http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/515/Configuration%20Options), thats all, but i keep getting errors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually pass an id to your script: e.g nicUpload.php?id=introPicHeader and it will become introPicHeader.jpg (or appropriate extension) in the images folder you defined.

However, I have noticed that this script is broken and cannot access the configuration option uploadURI if specified directly in nicEdit.js during the nicEditorAdvancedButton.extend({. This causes access to an relatively pathed "Unknown" resource, causing an error.

The documentation implies otherwise and the fact that the nicURI was specified here for imgur.com (maybe as a default) gave me the impression I could also add a uploadURI  reference to the nicUpload.php script in a single place rather than on every editor instantiation.

**Update**

This works if you pass it during instantiation, which I guess does allow for easy dynamic id population.

Unfortunately, the nicUpload.php is riddled with errors and it's output is not JSON. The editor expects to parse JSON and finds a script tag and errors with unexpected token "<".

There are a raft of other errors which I will attempt to identify:

In nicEdit.js

1. A.append("image") should be infact A.append("nicImage")
2. this.onUploaded(D.upload) should become this.onUploaded(D)
3. this.onUploaded(D) should be moved to within the try block after var D=JSON.parse(C.responseText) to fix variable scope issues
4. B.image.width needs to become B.width

In nicUpload.php

1. JSON output is not formed correctly, comment out html output and output just json_encode($status).
2. JSON output needs to return a key/value pair named links rather than url although renaming the var D=B.links to var D=B.url in nicEdit.js would also suffice as a fix.

Both php and javascript code leaves a lot to be desired, I get many errors regularly and have been fixing them myself.

Answer (score 2):

After looking for an solution a long time (lot of posts without real solution), i now fixed the code myself. I'm now able to upload an image to my own server. Thx to firebug and eclipse ;-)

The main problem is that the nicUpload.php is old and not working with the current nicEdit-Upload function.

*Missing is the error handling, feel free to add this...*

Add the **nicEditor to your php file and configure it** to use the nicEdit.php:

```
new nicEditor({iconsPath : 'pics/nicEditorIcons.gif', uploadURI : 'script/nicUpload.php'}
```

Download the **nicEdit.js uncompressed** and change the following lines in nicEdit.js:

```
uploadFile : function() {
var file = this.fileInput.files[0];
if (!file || !file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
  this.onError("Only image files can be uploaded");
  return;
}
this.fileInput.setStyle({ display: 'none' });
this.setProgress(0);

var fd = new FormData(); 
fd.append("image", file);
fd.append("key", "b7ea18a4ecbda8e92203fa4968d10660");
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", this.ne.options.uploadURI || this.nicURI);

xhr.onload = function() {
  try {
    var res = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  } catch(e) {
    return this.onError();
  }
  //this.onUploaded(res.upload); // CHANGE HERE
  this.onUploaded(res);
}.closure(this);
xhr.onerror = this.onError.closure(this);
xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
  this.setProgress(e.loaded / e.total);
}.closure(this);
xhr.send(fd);
```

},

```
onUploaded : function(options) {
this.removePane();
//var src = options.links.original; // CHANGE HERE
var src = options['url'];
if(!this.im) {
  this.ne.selectedInstance.restoreRng();
  //var tmp = 'javascript:nicImTemp();';
  this.ne.nicCommand("insertImage", src);
  this.im = this.findElm('IMG','src', src);
}
var w = parseInt(this.ne.selectedInstance.elm.getStyle('width'));
if(this.im) {
  this.im.setAttributes({
    src : src,
    width : (w && options.image.width) ? Math.min(w, options.image.width) : ''
  });
}
```

}

**Change the nicUpload.php like this**

```
<?php
/* NicEdit - Micro Inline WYSIWYG
 * Copyright 2007-2009 Brian Kirchoff
 *
 * NicEdit is distributed under the terms of the MIT license
 * For more information visit http://nicedit.com/
 * Do not remove this copyright message
 *
 * nicUpload Reciever Script PHP Edition
 * @description: Save images uploaded for a users computer to a directory, and
 * return the URL of the image to the client for use in nicEdit
 * @author: Brian Kirchoff <briankircho@gmail.com>
 * @sponsored by: DotConcepts (http://www.dotconcepts.net)
 * @version: 0.9.0
 */

/* 
* @author: Christoph Pahre
* @version: 0.1
* @description: different modification, so that this php file is working with the newest nicEdit.js (needs also modification - @see) 
* @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11677128/nicupload-says-invalid-upload-id-cant-make-it-works
*/

define('NICUPLOAD_PATH', '../images/uploadedImages'); // Set the path (relative or absolute) to
                                      // the directory to save image files

define('NICUPLOAD_URI', '../images/uploadedImages');   // Set the URL (relative or absolute) to
                                      // the directory defined above

$nicupload_allowed_extensions = array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif','bmp');

if(!function_exists('json_encode')) {
    die('{"error" : "Image upload host does not have the required dependicies (json_encode/decode)"}');
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') { // Upload is complete

    $file = $_FILES['image'];
    $image = $file['tmp_name'];
    $id = $file['name'];

    $max_upload_size = ini_max_upload_size();
    if(!$file) {
        nicupload_error('Must be less than '.bytes_to_readable($max_upload_size));
    }

    $ext = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file['name'], '.'), 1));
    @$size = getimagesize($image);
    if(!$size || !in_array($ext, $nicupload_allowed_extensions)) {
        nicupload_error('Invalid image file, must be a valid image less than '.bytes_to_readable($max_upload_size));
    }

    $filename = $id;
    $path = NICUPLOAD_PATH.'/'.$filename;

    if(!move_uploaded_file($image, $path)) {
        nicupload_error('Server error, failed to move file');
    }

    $status = array();
    $status['done'] = 1;
    $status['width'] = $size[0];
    $rp = realpath($path);
    $status['url'] =  NICUPLOAD_URI ."/".$id;


    nicupload_output($status, false);
    exit;
} 

// UTILITY FUNCTIONS

function nicupload_error($msg) {
    echo nicupload_output(array('error' => $msg)); 
}

function nicupload_output($status, $showLoadingMsg = false) {
    $script = json_encode($status);
    $script = str_replace("\\/", '/', $script);
    echo $script;

    exit;
}

function ini_max_upload_size() {
    $post_size = ini_get('post_max_size');
    $upload_size = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');
    if(!$post_size) $post_size = '8M';
    if(!$upload_size) $upload_size = '2M';

    return min( ini_bytes_from_string($post_size), ini_bytes_from_string($upload_size) );
}

function ini_bytes_from_string($val) {
    $val = trim($val);
    $last = strtolower($val[strlen($val)-1]);
    switch($last) {
        // The 'G' modifier is available since PHP 5.1.0
        case 'g':
            $val *= 1024;
        case 'm':
            $val *= 1024;
        case 'k':
            $val *= 1024;
    }
    return $val;
}

function bytes_to_readable( $bytes ) {
    if ($bytes<=0)
        return '0 Byte';

    $convention=1000; //[1000->10^x|1024->2^x]
    $s=array('B', 'kB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB');
    $e=floor(log($bytes,$convention));
    return round($bytes/pow($convention,$e),2).' '.$s[$e];
}

?>
```

Comment: Great solution, thank you! One thing - need to change `options.image.width` to `options.width` everywhere in javascript file.